# Need help editing Python code that squares numbers in a list?

Tags: python

I have a code for squaring each number in a list in Python, but I have issues with it. My code doesn't give me the right answer. If I have `[2,3,4,5,6,7]` the answer should be `[4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49]`, but I get `[49]`. Here’s my code:

```
numList = [2,3,4,5,6,7]
def square (N):
    sq = N * N
    return (sq)
def cmput_square(numList):
    i = 0
    L = []
    while i < len (numList):
        L = [square(numList[i])]
        i = i + 1
    return (L)
n = cmput_square (numList)
print ("The squares of your numbers are:", n)
```

Comment: use the `.append` method on your list. Doing `L = [square(numList[i])]` merely creates a *new list* with a single element each time and assigns it to `L`. So instead, use `L.append(numList[i])`

Comment: As a side note, `i = 0`, `while i < …`, `i = i + 1` is not a good way to do loops. `for i in range(len(numList)):` is much simpler (and more efficient, too). Or, even better, the only thing you're doing with `i` is `numList[i]`, so you can just skip that and do `for num in numList:`.

Comment: `map(lambda x: x**2, numList)` ?

Comment: @aws_apprentice: Why use `map` instead of a comprehension here? That means you have to create an otherwise-unnecessary function to wrap up the expression, and then you just have to convert it to a list to print it out at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are replacing `L` every time, instead of appending to `L`. The following should work:

```
numList = [2,3,4,5,6,7]
def square (N):
    sq = N * N
    return (sq)


def cmput_square(numList):
    i = 0
    L = []
    while i < len (numList):
        L.append(square(numList[i]))
        i = i + 1
    return (L)

n = cmput_square (numList)
print ("The squares of your numbers are:", n)
```

prints:

```
The squares of your numbers are: [4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49]
```

If you would like to reduce the number of lines of code required, you could change it to a single function with a list iteration:

```
def cmput_square(numList):
    return([i*i for i in numList])
```

**[EDIT]** Seeing as you can't use `.append` or a list comprehension as per your comment, here is another way, again as a single function. I'd argue it's less elegant, but it gets you what you need:

```
def cmput_square(numList):
    L = [0] * len(numList)
    for i in range(len(numList)):
        L[i] = numList[i]*numList[i]
    return(L)
```

**[EDIT #2]** and without using `for` or `range`, you can do it this way:

```
def cmput_square(numList):
    L = [0] * len(numList)
    i = 0
    while i < len(numList):
        L[i] = numList[i]*numList[i]
        i = i+1
    return(L)
```

Answer (score 0):

the current way you create your list overwrites L with a one item list each time it is called. You can either use `L.append(square(numList[i]))` instead of `L = [square(numList[i])]` of you can create the whole list in one line by a list comprehension:

```
def cmput_square(numList):
    return [square(i) for i in numlist]
```

Answer (score 0):

Happy birthday - just use .append()

```
numList = [2,3,4,5,6,7]
def square (N):
    sq = N * N
    return (sq)
def cmput_square(numList):
    i = 0
    L = []
    while i < len (numList):
        L.append(square(numList[i]))
        i += 1
    return (L)
n = cmput_square (numList)
print ("The squares of your numbers are:", n)
```

Answer (score -3):

replace

```
L = [square(numList[i])]
```

with

```
L += [square(numList[i])]
```

---

in case you wanted a shorter version:

```
numList = [2,3,4,5,6,7]
L = [numList[i]**2 for i in range(len(numList))]
print ("The squares of your numbers are:", L)
```